# Can an interface require a property, but not specify a required type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types, interface

I have a simple interface, defined as such:

```
interface iFace
{
   int Value { get; }
}
```

In this case, any class implementing iFace must have a property named Value of type int.  The usage of this interface is going to be with databinding, and I don't care what type the property is.  Do I have any options?  I'd like to avoid this solution:

```
interface iFace<T>
{
   T Value { get; }
}
```

as I'd like to refer to the interface without specifying type

Edit:

I'd like to be able able to apply the same interface to both a NumericUpDown control, and a Trackbar control.  One's value property is of type decimal, and the other is of type int.

Having the property be of type object wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: That's what the *dynamic* keyword was designed to do.

Comment: I'm relatively new to .net 3.5 and newer, I'll have to look into dynamic.

Comment: @HansPassant It deserves mentioning that a *dynamic* property will actually be typed as an *object*, so it will appear as such when the interface is used in another language -- and, presumably, when used in a C# project as an assembly reference.  I have no idea what would happen if it's used across projects as a project reference in a VS solution; I am curious.  If I remember to do so, I'll check it out when I get to work.

Comment: is writing interface is too hard and time consuming ? Cant you write another interface for int/double type... if you dont want generic interface? Generic interface is the solutin on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
interface MyInterface
{
    Object MyProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class MyClass : MyInterface
{
    Object MyInterface.MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return this.MyProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is MyType)
                this.MyProperty = (MyType)value;
        }
    }

    public MyType MyProperty
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is going to be the best answer.  I'm applying this interface to like 15+ controls, and I'm trying to avoid having to add an explicit interface to all of them.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't care whether it is strictly-typed, change the property type to object.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your edit:  You're coming up against the well-known problem that .NET has no `INumeric` interface.  It exists in source code I've seen, but it has been commented out, which implies that Microsoft has taken it seriously enough and run into some significant issues with it.

Danny Varod's solution is a good one; you can also extend it by creating a generic *and* a non-generic version of the interface.  Another solution is to add methods to the interface that represent the numeric operations for which you're now using mathematical operators, like `Increment()`, for example.

I'll call the interface `IHasValue` here (partly because it is somewhat comedic):

```
interface IHasValue
{
    object Value { get; set; }
    void Increment();
    void Decrement();
}

interface IHasValue<TValue> : IHasValue { new TValue Value { get; set; } }

abstract class UpDownValueControl<T> : IHasValue<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    object IHasValue.Value
    {
         get { return this.Value; }
         set { this.Value = (T)value; }
    }
    public abstract void Increment();
    public abstract void Decrement();
}
class NumericUpDownControl : UpDownValueControl<decimal>
{
    public override void Increment() { Value++; }
    public override void Decrement() { Value--; }
    //rest of the implementation
}
class TrackbarControl : UpDownValueControl<int>
{
    public override void Increment() { Value++; }
    public override void Decrement() { Value--; }
    //rest of the implementation
}
```

It's frustrating that the base class can't take care of repetitive code like the increment and decrement methods, but at least this approach allows the base class to take care of everything else *aside from* the repetitive mathematical operator code.

I suspect, in the end, that the complexity of this solution adds more cost than benefit; I think I'd be more likely to go with something like Danny Varod's solution.